# Where is phonegap pulling the splash screen from? Replaced all images in xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova

I went to the general tab of my project target in xcode, and changed all of the Launch Images to the ones that I want to see displayed. The preview shows they are the correct ones. I deleted the default images from the platforms/ios/app/resources/splash folder and replaced them with the correctly labeled and correctly sized custom images. AND STILL, phonegap is still using it's default image for the splash screen.

Where is it even pulling that image from? Am I missing a step? I'm using phonegap 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Hello i think you have change the images in wrong directory. you need to replace images in the below splash folder. i have attached screenshot where you need to change the files. [image]

Hope this helps.